# How can I reuse the previous position in vertex shader of glsl?

Tags: glsl, webgl

I am using glsl.

How can I reuse the previous position, save the value and pass it to next render,

```
varying vec2 vUv;
varying vec3 vPosition;
varying vec3 vNormal;

vec3 computeCurl(vec3 p) {
//curl noise function
}

void main() {
vUv = uv;
vPosition = position;
vNormal = normal;
vec3 newPos = computeCurl(previousPos);
gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(newPos, 1.0);
}
```

Update the new position by previous position
The value of previousPos is the same as the value of previous newPos.

```
vec3 newPos = computeCurl(previousPos);
```

Is it possible to save the newPos value somewhere? Then, I can uniform the value for next rendering.

Comment: I don't see a loop here. Also, what do you mean by "previous"? Do you mean from the last rendering command? Do you mean from the vertex before this one in the sequence of vertices?

Comment: Yes, the previous position is come from the last rendering. The position will be updated with a curl function every rendering.

Comment: [transform feedback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLTransformFeedback)